# HTMLScriptElement attributes is empty on iOS browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, working-copy-app

Environment:

ipad mini 9.2.1

The code works on chrome/safari on PC.

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        // ...
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var script = document.head.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            console.log(script);
            var scriptSrc = script.getAttribute("src");
            console.log(scriptSrc);

            var attrs = script.attributes;
            console.log(attrs);
            console.log(attrs.length);
            console.log(attrs[0]);
        </script>
        // ...
    </head>
</html>
```

The output is:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
jquery-1.11.3.min.js
NamedNodeMap {0: src, length: 1}
1
src=​"jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
```

And this demo works fine on my iPad with safari/chrome as well.

But, when I try to run it with a embed browser in an git app: [Working Copy](http://workingcopyapp.com) on my iPad, the output was wrong:

```
[object HTMLScriptElement]
null
[object NamedNodeMap]
0
undefined
```

I am really curious to know what could be the reason causing this problem...

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

**UPDATE:**

After moving the

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

from `<head>` to `<body>` section solved the problem, now the output is the same as in PC browser.

But still not sure what caused this problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the developer of Working Copy.

The app injects some JavaScript into the head element to catch exceptions and capture log statements. It seems to interfere with jQuery somehow.

I will try to make this injection in a more robust way to make your original example work.